# Should I get 1 hero to lvl 100 or all to lvl 74

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I have a Series EV lvl 60 so should I lvl her up to 100 or lvl 74 and get all my other heroes to lvl 74?

Comment: Start at 74 so you can use mythic gear, then work to the next tier. Level 100 takes a LONG time to hit. Especially when you get above 80. A full NMHC survival run wont even get me an entire level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the simple answer is, why not both? Level another champ up to 74 first, so you can get a feel for them rather than being stuck with an EV. I recommend a Monk - great for playing as a tower or DPS build, or a squire / mage. Hell, they're all good.

Level 60 is quite easy to hit with the right build / strategy. If you can, find someone to run Glitterhelm Caverns on Nightmare (or Insane, usually safer / quicker). I used to do so for people, and it took roughly 10 minutes to beat GC on Insane without letting a mob through, and leveling them up to 60-ish in one run. A couple more runs and people were at 70+.

As stated, Mythic gear is awesome, and much better than Godly or below. It is well-coveted, and a good set could carry you through past the next-tier armour easily.

This is only applicable to the normal Dungeon Defenders game, not Eternity, as I haven't played Eternity.

Answer (score 1):

I would get other characters to 74 first. I've had the most luck in Nightmare runs with defenses built from multiple heroes.  Of note is the Summoner, although they are a DLC character. The minions the Summoner has do not use DU, instead they use MU (Monster Units).
The Monk's Auras are also very useful, especially Slow Aura.